# Gorilla/mux SPA does not serve static directory correctly

Tags: go, single-page-application, gorilla

I'm trying to make an SPA web app and took this sample from the gorilla mux package
https://github.com/gorilla/mux#serving-single-page-applications
But it didn't work before I made some changes in path like it described there https://github.com/gorilla/mux/issues/588

When I open in browser some path http://localhost:8080/somepage it serves the index.html and related files(css and js). But if I enter path with another slash e.g http://localhost:8080/somepage/smt it also serves index.html but js and css don't work, and theirs code is changed to the code which is in index.html. So I have my js or css file with exact same code as in index.html. I have no idea why it is and how the sample of the package works.

Here is my code

```
func (h spaHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path, err := filepath.Abs(r.URL.Path)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    path = filepath.Join(h.staticPath, r.URL.Path)
    _, err = os.Stat(path)
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        //this called if the path is like that http://localhost:8080/any or ...any/somesubpage
        http.ServeFile(w, r, filepath.Join(h.staticPath, h.indexPath))
        return
    } else if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("500")
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    //this called if the path is just http://localhost:8080
    http.FileServer(http.Dir(h.staticPath)).ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    //api handlers

    spa := spaHandler{staticPath: "./", indexPath: "index.html"}
    router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(spa)

    srv := &http.Server{
        Handler: router,
        Addr:    "127.0.0.1:8080",
    }

    log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
}
```

staticPath is ./ because if my index.html is in some folder this absolutely won't work.

I used this sample in Ubuntu without changes and it worked well. Maybe because of differences in working of filepath. But I need it on Windows.

Or maybe there are other ways of making spa in go?

Comment: Please show how `index.html` is referencing the js/css files. I'd guess you are using relative paths (if so adding a `/` at the front should fix your issue).

Comment: @Brits I removed the dot from the beginning of link and it worked. Thank you. <link rel="stylesheet" href="./client/style.css" type="text/css"/> to <link rel="stylesheet" href="/client/style.css" type="text/css"/>. Can you please explain why it works so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will return `index.html` if the requested file does not exist; for example if the request is for `http://address.com/foo/bar/xxx.html` (and there is no `xxx.html` in that path) then the `index.html` file will be returned. The issue is that if `index.html` includes `<script  src="test.js"></script>` (or `src=./test.js`) then the script tag will result in the browser requesting `http://address.com/foo/bar/test.js` (because the path is [relative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#examples_of_relative_urls) and the path of the original request was `/foo/bar/`) and this will not return the expected file (`index.html` will be returned because the requested file does not exist!).

Changing your html to an use [absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#examples_of_absolute_urls) path (e.g. `<script  src="/test.js"></script>`) means the correct javascript (or other file type) will be requested regardless of the original request path.